# AngularJS Spring mvc @RequestParam

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm newbie in Angularjs,The following Spring controller get object from database by id I want to
get This id by @RequestParam using AngularJs ,I try the following code but get this error
"Error: id is not defined
.findOne@ localhost:8080/myapp/scripts/services.js:126:79
$scope.findOne@ localhost:8080/myapp/scripts/controllers.js:280:4

Spring MVC Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/chartConfigs/getById",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @RolesAllowed(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
    public ChartConfigs findOne(@RequestParam(value = "id") Integer id) {
     System.out.println(chartConfigService.getOne(id));
         return chartConfigService.getOne(id);

    }
```

AngularJS Service

```
    myappApp.factory('ChartConfigService', function ($http) {
    return {
    findOne: function() {
        var promise = $http.get('app/rest/chartConfigs/getById',{params: {id: id}}).
                        then(function  (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        return promise;
    }
  }
 });
```

AngularJS Controller

```
  myappApp.controller('ChartConfigController', function ($scope, ChartConfigService) {
    $scope.findOne= function() {
     ChartConfigService.findOne($scope.id).then(function(obj) {
            $scope.message=obj;
            console.log(obj.type);
        });
    };      
  });
```

Html page

```
 <input ng-model="id" ng-change="findOne()" required>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass id to **findOne** as a function parameter:

```
findOne: function(id) {
        var promise = $http.get('app/rest/chartConfigs/getById',{params: {'id': id}}).
                        then(function  (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        return promise;
    }
```