# How can I get the value of a string in ui-grid angular selection and pass it to the Spring controller

Tags: javascript

How can I get the value of a string in ui-grid angular selection and pass it to the Spring controller.

I tried everything, it doesn’t work.

My JS file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.cellNav']);
app.controller(

'StudentCtrl', ['$scope', 'StudentService', '$http',



        function ($scope, StudentService) {

                var paginationOptions = {
                    pageNumber: 1,
                    pageSize: 5,
                    sort: null
                };

                StudentService.getStudents(
                    paginationOptions.pageNumber,
                    paginationOptions.pageSize).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.gridOptions.data = data.content;
                });

                $scope.gridOptions = {
                    paginationPageSizes: [5, 10, 20],
                    paginationPageSize: paginationOptions.pageSize,
                    enableColumnMenus: false,
                    useExternalPagination: true,
                    columnDefs: [
                        {
                            name: 'id',
                            field: 'id',
                        },

                        {
                            name: 'productName',
                            field: 'productName'
                        },

                        {
                            name: 'price',
                            field: 'price'
                        },
                    ],


                    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                        gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged(
                            $scope,
                            function (newPage, pageSize) {
                                paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
                                paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
                                StudentService.getStudents(newPage, pageSize)
                                    .success(function (data) {
                                        $scope.gridOptions.data = data.content;
                                    });

                            });

                    }
                };
            }

        ]
    );
    app.service('StudentService', ['$http', function ($http) {

        function getStudents(pageNumber, size) {
            pageNumber = pageNumber > 0 ? pageNumber - 1 : 0;
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'student/get?page=' + pageNumber + '&size=' + size
            });
        }

        return {
            getStudents: getStudents
        };

    }]);
```

My controller Spring

```
@PostMapping
    public String placeYourOrder(Order order, Model model,
                                 @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                                 Map<String, Object> orderNumberModel,
                                 @RequestParam(value="productName")String productName) {

        orderService.saveOrder(order, user, productName);
        List<Order> orders = orderRepository.findAll();
        List<Order> orderNumberByUserName = orderRepository.findOrderNumberByUserName(user.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("orders", orders);
        if (Component.isUser()) {
            orderNumberModel.put("orderNumber", orderNumberByUserName);
            return "orderNumber";
        } else return "orderList";
    }
}
```

I need to pass to the @RequestParam parameter, which forms an order based on the goods in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Write template for the 'productName' column. Since you haven't mentioned when the 'http call' is made I assume its called on Click of 'productName' on each row.

Refer this url
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20317%20Custom%20Templates

If your cell template is as below

```
{ field: 'click', cellTemplate: '<div class="btn primary" ng-click="grid.appScope.placeYourOrder(row)"><span ng-bind="row.entity.productName"></span></div>' }
```

Alternatively you can choose to write row-template if you want to call the service if clicked anywhere in a row.

You can pass the entire row to the method, get only the required fields, form the request and call the service.

Refer this url to pass RequestParam
[AngularJS Spring mvc @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779801/angularjs-spring-mvc-requestparam)

Hope this helps.